# When can a Python object be pickled

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle

I'm doing a fair amount of parallel processing in Python using the multiprocessing module.  I know certain objects CAN be pickle (thus passed as arguments in multi-p) and others can't.  E.g.

```
class abc():
    pass

a=abc()
pickle.dumps(a)
'ccopy_reg\n_reconstructor\np1\n(c__main__\nabc\np2\nc__builtin__\nobject\np3\nNtRp4\n.'
```

But I have some larger classes in my code (a dozen methods, or so), and this happens:

```
a=myBigClass()
pickle.dumps(a)
Traceback (innermost last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/usr/apps/Python279/python-2.7.9-rhel5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle file objects
```

It's not a file object, but at other times, I'll get other messages that say basically:  "I can't pickle this".

So what's the rule?  Number of bytes?  Depth of hierarchy?  Phase of the moon?

Comment: Have you tried dill? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill 

It enhances `pickle` possibilities a lot.

Comment: I actually just tried dill and it works, but it's not part of our build, so I'll have to request it from the system administrator's.  Still wonder what the 'rule' is though.

Comment: @PaulNelson If you're going to use `dill`, you can't use `multiprocessing`. The `dill` author has a `multiprocessing` fork called `pathos` you have to use instead.

Comment: @PaulNelson You can probably get away with implementing `__getstate__`/`__setstate__` on the `myBigClass` class to remove the unpicklable parts from the class' state prior to pickling, if you can't completely replace `multiprocessing`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm the `dill` author. There's a fairly comprehensive list of what pickles and what doesn't as part of `dill`.  It can be run per version of Python 2.5–3.4, and adjusted for what pickles with `dill` or what pickles with `pickle` by changing one flag. See [here](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/blob/master/tests/test_objects.py) and [here](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/blob/master/dill/_objects.py).

The root of the rules for what pickles is (off the top of my head):

1. Can you capture the state of the object by reference (i.e. a
   function defined in `__main__` versus an imported function)? [*Then, yes*]
2. Does a generic `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` rule exist for the given object type? [*Then, yes*]
3. Does it depend on a `Frame` object (i.e. rely on the GIL and global execution stack)?  Iterators are now an exception to this, by "replaying" the iterator on unpickling. [*Then, no*]
4. Does the object instance point to the wrong class path (i.e. due to being defined in a closure, in C-bindings, or other `__init__` path manipulations)? [*Then, no*]
5. Is it considered dangerous by Python to allow this? [*Then, no*]

So, (5) is less prevalent now than it used to be, but still has some lasting effects in the language for `pickle`.  `dill`, for the most part, removes (1), (2), and (5) – but is still fairly effected by (3) and (4).

I might be forgetting something else, but I think in general those are the underlying rules.

Certain modules like `multiprocessing` register some objects that are important for their functioning. `dill` registers the majority of objects in the language.

The `dill` fork of `multiprocessing` is required because `multiprocessing` uses `cPickle`, and `dill` can only augment the pure-Python pickling registry.  You could, if you have the patience, go through all the relevant `copy_reg` functions in `dill`, and apply them to the `cPickle` module and you'd get a much more pickle-capable `multiprocessing`.  I've found a simple (read: one liner) way to do this for `pickle`, but not `cPickle`.

Comment: Very helpful. Could you comment more on item 4? What did you mean by "wrong class path"?

Comment: Sure, I mean, is the `__name__` and `__module__` correct if they exist, or was the object generated (or aliased) in such a way that those attributes are incorrect and/or potentially missing.

Comment: Thanks. I had this problem but it turns out that as you said, C extension is not pickle-able. I searched around and found that to define "__reduce__" function could solve this. I'm still researching on this topic but hopefully someone else checked this post would beneift.

Comment: BTW, can dill pickle objects created from C extension?

Comment: It depends, see the rules above.

Answer (score 8):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled):

> The following types can be pickled:
>
> - `None`, `True`, and `False`
> - integers, long integers, floating point numbers, complex numbers
> - normal and Unicode strings
> - tuples, lists, sets, and dictionaries containing only picklable objects
> - functions defined at the top level of a module
>
>   - built-in functions defined at the top level of a module
> - classes that are defined at the top level of a module
> - instances of such classes whose `__dict__` or the result of calling `__getstate__()` is picklable (see section The pickle protocol for details).
>
> Attempts to pickle unpicklable objects will raise the `PicklingError`
>   exception; when this happens, an unspecified number of bytes may have
>   already been written to the underlying file. Trying to pickle a highly
>   recursive data structure may exceed the maximum recursion depth, a
>   `RuntimeError` will be raised in this case. You can carefully raise this
>   limit with `sys.setrecursionlimit()`.

Comment: As stated later in the docs it is also possible to define the `__reduce__` and `__setstate__` and `__getstate__` methods to make arbitrary objects picklable, or to use persistent ids to refer to global objets such as files.

Answer (score 3):

The general rule of thumb is that "logical" objects can be pickled, but "resource" objects (files, locks) can't, because it makes no sense to persist/clone them.

Comment: I disagree that it "makes no sense".  For example, how is a memory-mapped array different than a buffer array, save that it has a file-backend?  Should those not be treated similarly in certain cases?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to icedtrees' answer, also coming straight from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pickle.html#pickle-inst), you can customize and control how class instances are pickled and unpicked, using the special methods: `object.__getnewargs_ex__()`, `object.__getnewargs__()`, `object.__getstate__()`, `object.__setstate__(state)`