# TypeError: can't pickle _asyncio.Future objects

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, future, discord.py

I'm trying to save a list to the file using pickle after it was modified in my discord.py bot. But when the bot tries to pickle a list and save it I get an error. already tried to make `updateChannels()` async with same error

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/popek/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 177, in on_message
    updateChannels()
  File "bot.py", line 151, in updateChannels
    pickle.dump(channels, f)
TypeError: can't pickle _asyncio.Future objects
```

```py
import discord
import asyncio
import pickle

channels = []
try:
    with open('channels.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        channels = pickle.load(f)
except TypeError:
    pass

client = discord.Client()

def updateChannels():
    global channels
    with open('channels.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        pickle.dump(channels, f)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global channels
    if message.content == ".enable":
        if message.channel in channels:
            await message.channel.send("Auto-messages already enabled on this channel")
        else:
            channels.append(message.channel)
            updateChannels()
            await message.channel.send("Enabled auto-messages on this channel")
    # same for disabling

client.run("[TOKEN]")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When can a Python object be pickled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29922373/when-can-a-python-object-be-pickled)

Comment: I replaced pickle with dill and got the same error with very long traceback: https://pastebin.com/42spuXr7 (Used `import dill as pickle`)

Comment: Sorry if my comment wasn't clear, I didn't mean to suggest that you should use dill, I was hoping the question would provide some useful information on this class/type of issue.

Comment: You won't be able to pickle channel objects directly because they possess complex state that involves network sockets and interaction with the server. Instead, pickle a list of identifiers (e.g. channel names or URLs, whatever you have) which you can later use to reconstruct actual channels.

Comment: ok now i understand. thx for help